# An ArUco grid without any seperation space between markers

Tags: opencv, augmented-reality, aruco

The OpenCV's implementation of ArUco extracts a rectangle containing the marker and then proceeds with decoding and error correction, meaning that the marker's borders must have a decent contrast with the background.

The bigger question is: what if we have border occlusion, or the border isn't visible at all? Can't we still detect the maker using the white high-contrast area and their unique shape?

My actual problem is that I have an ArUco grid and I simply want to remove the separation between the markers and stitch them together. In this case, borders are gone, so OpenCV fails to detect any of the markers.

OpenCV prevented generating such grids in `cv.aruco.GridBoard` by requiring `markerSeparation` to be greater than 0.

I am wondering if there are any other implementations that don't use the border to detect markers and actually use the pattern itself, Or even a different fiducial marker?

My grid:
[image: My 2*6 grid]

Comment: please show such a grid. -- if you'd like to write a scientific paper on recovering the pose of an AR marker from anything other than the edges of its square outline, please go ahead. I know of no such attempts. it seems counterproductive to attempt.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I added the image. And I must say that even the borders of this image might be missing.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz All that I'm saying is why we bother to use complicated encodings at all if we only care about the rectangle. I don't know if you have seen RUNE-Tag before, but I'm considering using those sorts of things. In my opinion, The ability to detect data points individually and then decide which is a false-positive accordingly is an accuracy and performance boost.